# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una tupla y una lista en Python?

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

En Python puedo añadir valores en una lista utilizando la función append() entre otras cosas, pero con las tuplas todo esto cambia y la forma en la que se manipulan es diferente. Su estructura parece muy similar a la de una lista, y quisiera saber su utilidad o propósito.

Las tuplas en Python tienen esta estructura:

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
```

Mientras que las listas esta otra:

```
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

Agradecería si alguien puede explicarme porque son necesarias las tuplas en Python y en que casos se deben utilizar.

Comment: Una tupla es similar a una lista... pero es inmutable! Una lista puede estirarse, puede modificarse... [una tupla no](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_change_tuple_item.asp). Si intentas modificar una tupla, python te tira error. Ese es el principal uso de las tuplas **que yo conozco**: Cuando necesitas tener un conjunto de valores que no vayan a cambiar.

Comment: Me parece muy curioso ya que python siempre ha sido un lenguaje sin restricciones de ese tipo, por ejemplo no existen las variables constantes.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/626759/

Comment: Efectivamente, no es un lenguaje muy "restrictivo", pero la inmutabilidad puede ser necesaria en algunos momentos. Por ejemplo, a partir de python 3.8 **SI** existen las [variables finales en python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/)

Comment: Me parece que a esta pregunta le hace falta investigación ... vamos a sobre escribir la documentacion de python en SOes???

Comment: Yo investigué bien y creo que eso se evidencia en la forma en la que planteé la pregunta. No todos dominamos a cabalidad el ingles y ese es el motivo por el cual SOes fue creado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La única diferencia es que las tuplas son inmutables y las listas no.

Esta distinción puede ser importante por dos razones:

- Puedes querer tener un "grupo" de valores para pasarlo como parámetro a una función, pero quieres estar seguro de que la función no te va a modificar ninguno de los valores del grupo. Ya que en python todo son referencias, una vez la función recibe la referencia al "grupo" (una lista, un objeto) puede cambiar sus valores. La única forma de evitarlo es hacer que ese grupo sea una tupla. De hecho te sugiero investigar también las [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) que son un mecanismo para crear algo que parece un objeto (con sus campos con nombre) pero que está implementado en realidad internamente como una tupla, para que sea inmutable.

  Este caso de uso es más importante de lo que parece a primera vista. Yo me he vuelto loco depurando código en el que al final el bug estaba causado porque una lista de datos no tenía los datos que yo había cargado en ella sino otros, porque alguna de las múltiples funciones que la recibía como parámetro la modificaba. Al final lo resolví cambiando todas mis listas por tuplas y viendo dónde rompía el programa cuando una función intentaba modificar el dato.

  Gracias a las tuplas y las `namedtuples` pude refactorizar el programa de modo que todas las funciones sean *puras* (no causen efectos secundarios sobre variables que no pertenecen a la función). Esto es mucho más fácil de depurar y mantener.
- Casi más importante, al ser inmutables también son *hasheables*. Es decir, se puede aplicar sobre ellas la función `hash()` y el resultado será siempre el mismo. En una lista obviamente el hash podría cambiar si los elementos de la lista han cambiado.

  El que un dato sea *hasheable* es importante porque sólo los datos hasheables pueden ser guardados en un conjunto (`set()`) o pueden ser usados como claves de un diccionario (pues estas estructuras de datos son en el fondo tablas hash).

  Por tanto, si te encuentras ante la necesidad de usar una lista como clave en un diccionario, verás que no puedes. Conviértela en tupla y ya podrás.

Comment: Es importante señalar que para que una tupla sea _hashable_ todos sus items han de ser inmutables. Por ejemplo, `hash( (1, [2]) )` dará error.

Answer (score 20):

La principal diferencia es que **las tuplas son inmutables** (No pueden ser modificadas) y las listas no. Esta inmutabilidad hace que se le pueda aplicar una **función hash**

Otro tema muy importante es que **las tuplas son más eficientes que las listas**. Por lo que a menos que necesites la mutabilidad en tu estructura de datos, es más conveniente usar una tupla en vez de una lista. Vamos a ver el por qué en detalle.

## 1. Compilación

**Python reconoce y evalúa las tuplas como expresiones constantes en el momento de compilación**, en vez de en la ejecución, esto es conocido como [Constant Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). Puedo demostrarte esto con el módulo `disassembly` de Python

```
from dis import dis

#Vemos lo que sucede en la compilación
print("Tupla al compilar:\n")
print(dis(compile('(1,2,3, "a")', 'string', 'eval')))
print("\nLista al compilar:\n")
print(dis(compile('[1,2,3, "a"]', 'string', 'eval')))
```

**Salida**

```
Tupla al compilar:

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3, 'a'))
              2 RETURN_VALUE

Lista al compilar:

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('a')
              8 BUILD_LIST               4
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Efectivamente, Python ha evaluado la tupla como una expresión constante y la ha retornado, sin embargo en la lista, ha tenido que evaluar cada elemento de la lista como una constante, después construir la lista y por último retornarla. Esto por supuesto tiene un **coste de tiempo** vamos a verlo

```
from timeit import timeit

print("Tupla: ", timeit("(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)", number=15_000_000))
print("Lista: ", timeit("[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]", number=15_000_000))
```

**Salida:**

```
Tupla:  0.09676512900114176
Lista:  0.9273542539995105
```

**Una tupla es aproximadamente 10 veces más rápido**

#### Advertencia

Este comportamiento sucede porque la tupla la hemos creado con elementos inmutables, **con que solo uno de los elementos fuera mutable**, la tupla sería evaluada por Python igual que la lista y los tiempos serían similares.

## 2. Copiar

Cuando quieres copiar una lista, Python vuelve a reservar memoria para crear una nueva lista. En el caso de las tuplas, debido a su inmutabilidad, no se copia, simplemente se crea **una referencia** [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy). Vamos a demostrarlo:

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista_2 = list(lista_1)
print("Lista copiadas: ", hex(id(lista_1)), hex(id(lista_2)))

tupla_1 = (1,2,3,4,5)
tupla_2 = tuple(tupla_1)
print("Tupla copiada:  ", hex(id(tupla_1)), hex(id(tupla_2)))
```

**Salida:**

```
Lista copiadas:  0x7f9cc80bb960 0x7f9cc17a9500
Tupla copiada:   0x7f9cc8101bf0 0x7f9cc8101bf0
```

**Al copiar la lista se encuentran en distintas posiciones de memoria** sin embargo la tupla está en la misma posición de memoria.

Esto también tiene un impacto en los **tiempos de ejecución**:

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit("tuple((1,2,3,4,5))", number=5_000_000)
timeit("list((1,2,3,4,5))", number=5_000_000)
```

**Salida**

```
Lista copiadas:  0.5346233499985829
Tupla copiadas:  0.3198905820026994
```

Véase que **he copiado la lista de una tupla**, para evitar incluir el tiempo de creación extra que tiene una lista (lo que vimos en el punto 1) y que **así nos fijemos exclusivamente en el copiado** y sea una **comparación justa**.

## 3. Almacenamiento

El almacenamiento para una tupla es exacto, es decir Python reserva el espacio justo y necesario para almacenar una tupla, ya que es inmutable. En las listas es distinto, Python reserva más espacio del necesario para una lista, lo que se conoce como *Overallocation* y *pre-allocate* con el objetivo de optimizar la entrada de elementos en dicha lista. Si quieres saber más, puedes ver [Dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). Vamos a ver esto:

```
print("Almacenamiento Tupla")
t = tuple()
previa = sys.getsizeof(t)
for n in range(10):
    tupla = tuple(range(n + 1))
    tamano_tupla = sys.getsizeof(tupla)
    diferencia, previa = tamano_tupla - previa, tamano_tupla
    print(f"{n+1} Espacio reservado: {tamano_tupla}, diferencia={diferencia}")

print("\nAlmacenamiento Lista")
t = list()
previa = sys.getsizeof(t)
for n in range(10):
    lista = list(range(n + 1))
    tamano_lista = sys.getsizeof(lista)
    diferencia, previa = tamano_lista - previa, tamano_lista
    print(f"{n+1} Espacio reservado: {tamano_lista}, diferencia={diferencia}")
```

**Salida:**

```
Almacenamiento Tupla
1 Espacio reservado: 64, diferencia=8
2 Espacio reservado: 72, diferencia=8
3 Espacio reservado: 80, diferencia=8
4 Espacio reservado: 88, diferencia=8
5 Espacio reservado: 96, diferencia=8
6 Espacio reservado: 104, diferencia=8
7 Espacio reservado: 112, diferencia=8
8 Espacio reservado: 120, diferencia=8
9 Espacio reservado: 128, diferencia=8
10 Espacio reservado: 136, diferencia=8

Almacenamiento Lista
1 Espacio reservado: 104, diferencia=32
2 Espacio reservado: 112, diferencia=8
3 Espacio reservado: 120, diferencia=8
4 Espacio reservado: 128, diferencia=8
5 Espacio reservado: 136, diferencia=8
6 Espacio reservado: 144, diferencia=8
7 Espacio reservado: 152, diferencia=8
8 Espacio reservado: 168, diferencia=16
9 Espacio reservado: 200, diferencia=32
10 Espacio reservado: 208, diferencia=8
```

Efectivamente la tupla siempre reserva 8 bytes y ocupa el espacio justo de los elementos, sin embargo la lista ocupa más espacio y hace reservas de memoria distintas.

Esto se debe a que Python al reservar más memoria de la necesaria utiliza un algoritmo que fijándose en el tamaño de la lista, calcula cuando espacio más va a reservar. Así si por ejemplo usamos `.append()` y **la lista crece, nos evitamos tener que volver a reservar espacio** para introducir el elemento, ya que dicho espacio está previamente reservado.

## Bonus

Otro tema que viene asociado, pero que se puede pasar por alto es que al ser inmutable, el orden se mantiene, es decir en las tuplas **el orden en el que vienen los elementos tiene significado.**

Answer (score 6):

SEGÚN **recursospython.com**.

Una lista no es lo mismo que una tupla, ambas son un conjunto ordenado de valores, en donde este último puede ser cualquier objeto: un número, una cadena, una función, una clase, una instancia, etc.

La diferencia es que las listas presentan una serie de funciones adicionales que permiten un amplio manejo de los valores que contienen. Basándonos en esta definición, puede decirse que las listas son dinámicas, mientras que las tuplas son estáticas.