# ¿ Las tuplas son mas eficientes porque se almacenan en algun sitio especifico?

Tags: python

El hecho de que las tuplas sean inmutables me hace pensar que puedan llegar a tener un trato especial de parte del interprete de python, hasta llegar a ser almacenadas en algún sitio especifico que no sea la RAM (*equivalente por ejemplo al uso de la palabra clave `register` en el lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c)*).

De hecho en [este tutorial en Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rrbg7w6Ezps)  (alrededor del minuto [9:40](https://youtu.be/Rrbg7w6Ezps?t=580)) se dice precisamente eso, que el almacenamiento de las tuplas ocurre en un lugar "especial" de la memoria.

> ¿Es cierto esto? ¿almacena el intérperete las tuplas en un sitio especifico que las hace mas eficientes?

Comment: Se guardan en RAM ...

Comment: @abulafia Del primer tutorial de python que vi, hace ya varios meses...

Comment: @https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rrbg7w6Ezps&list=PLCTD_CpMeEKRppvi86Dy8CPYZ8-XzN2qu&index=31 minuto 9:45 mas o menos

Comment: @abulafia supongo que tendre que tener mas cuidado con los sitios de los que saco informacion.. Gracias por la aclaratoria.

Comment: Cuatro votos si no la reformula :P (Puede ser muy útil!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no tendría sentido que el intérprete usara los registros para almacenar una tupla, a menos que esa tupla estuviera formando parte de un cálculo dentro de un bucle en el que se la estuviera accediendo una y otra vez. Pero al tratarse de un lenguaje interpretado Python es bastante "miope" y solo ve la instrucción que está ejecutando. No ve el código completo para poder realizar ese tipo de optimizaciones.

No obstante sí que puede realizar otro tipo de optimizaciones. Debido a que son inmutables, si en una parte del programa se hace algo como:

```
a = (1, 2)
```

y en otra parte del programa se hace algo como:

```
b = (1, 2)
```

el intérprete podría decidir que el objeto tupla que contiene ese par de números `(1,2)` exista **una sola vez en memoria**, y que `a` y `b` se refieran al mismo objeto. No hay problema con esa decisión, ya que el objeto es inmutable por lo que no se corre el riesgo de que al cambiarlo a través de `a`, se tenga el efecto secundario de que  `b` cambia.

Puedes verificar si tu intérprete ha realizado ese tipo de optimización usando el operador `is` que te devuelve `True` cuando dos variables apuntan a un mismo objeto. He comprobado que mi Python sí realiza esta optimización si ejecutas un .py (aunque no la realiza si haces el experimento en el intérprete interactivo):

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (1, 2)

print(a is b)  # ---> Sale True
```

También funciona con tuplas vacías:

```
a = tuple()
b = tuple()

print(a is b) # ---> Sale True
```

Es más, en el caso de la tupla vacía resulta que esa tupla (vacía) está creada de antemano como parte del intérprete. Cada vez que el programa requiera una tupla vacía, se reusa esa misma previamente creada. Esto podemos comprobarlo usando la función `id()` que devuelve un identificador único del objeto. Dos objetos con el mismo `id`, son el mismo objeto. En particular el intérprete CPython te da la dirección de memoria en que está guardado como resultado de `id()`

Pues podemos crear una variable `a` con una tupla vacía, ver su `id()`, destruir esa variable (con `del a`), y teóricamente el recolector de basura debería eliminar de memoria la tupla vacía. Pero como es una tupla pre-creada, no lo hace. Si creamos de nuevo `a` veremos que tiene el mismo `id` que la primera vez.

```
a = tuple()
print(id(a))  # ---> 4462485568
del a

a = tuple()
print(id(a))  # ---> 4462485568
```

Esto también funciona con una tupla como `(1,2)` (de nuevo, sólo al ejecutar un .py y no en el intérprete interactivo), lo que denota que el recolector de basura no elimina realmente las tuplas sino que las conserva por si es necesario usarlas otra vez poco después. Esto no lo hace para todas las tuplas, naturalmente, sino que mantiene una especie de *cache* y va eliminando las que detecta que no se usan.

El intérprete hace otras optimizaciones con las tuplas. Por ejemplo aunque internamente las guarda en un array C, cuando toca liberar ese array (por el recolector de basura), es posible que en vez de liberarlo lo guarde en una lista enlazada de "espacio disponible", por si va a necesitar enseguida crear otra tupla del mismo tamaño, poder reusar esa memoria. Eso le permite ahorrar memoria, y sobre todo **reduce** la cantidad de operaciones `malloc()` y `free()` necesarias. Esto puede traducirse en un código ligeramente más veloz que si hubiéramos usado listas en lugar de tuplas para estas variables `a` y `b`, pero no porque las tuplas se guarden en una memoria más veloz, sino porque el código que usa el intérprete para manejarlas requiere menos operaciones internamente.

Tiene sentido que aplique este tipo de optimizaciones a las tuplas (y no a listas por ejemplo) porque precisamente por ser las tuplas inmutables, es más frecuente que se creen y destruyan sin parar. Si queremos añadir un elemento a una tupla mediante por ejemplo `a=(1,2); a+=(3,4)` (operación válida), lo que ocurre es que se crea una tupla nueva con `(1,2,3,4)` y se descarta la antigua con `(1, 2)`, ya que la original no se puede cambiar (es inmutable). Ya que las tuplas están por tanto sujetas a muchas creaciones y eliminaciones, son a priori **más ineficientes** que las listas, y por tanto el intérprete se esfuerza en optimizar la gestión de la memoria para ellas.

En definitiva, las tuplas *no son más eficientes* que las listas en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución, más bien al contrario, y eso fuerza al intérprete a hacer ciertos malabarismos para que la penalización no sea tan grande. Sí pueden ser más eficientes en el uso de memoria, ya que no es necesario realizar copias de ellas. Muchas tuplas iguales son en realidad la misma (más detalles en [esta respuesta de Alberto Rubiales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/415526/156415) ¡Gracias @revliscano por señalarla!)

La gran ventaja de las tuplas no es su supuesta eficiencia (que hemos visto que es prácticamente marginal), sino su inmutabilidad. El tener un tipo de datos que no se pueda cambiar es útil en ocasiones para hacer programas más robustos, pues aunque a veces la intención del programador es no cambiar una lista, ocurre que quizás alguna función (a veces no escrita por él) acaba cambiándola y es difícil detectar dónde ocurrió. Si usas en su lugar una tupla, el intento de modificación hará saltar una excepción.

Comment: Solo para complementar esta respuesta: Hay ciertos criterios dentro de los cuales las tuplas sí resultan ser más eficientes, como bien señala [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/415526/156415) de Alberto Rubiales.

Comment: @revliscano Gracias por el apunte. He añadido el enlace como parte de mi respuesta, y he cambiado otra parte al comprobar que sí que se reutilizan tuplas borradas o asignadas a diferentes variables. En mis experimentos me salía que no, pero era porque probé en el intérprete interactivo. Repitiendo los experimentos desde un script.py el resultado es diferente.

Comment: La única ventaja de usar _tuplas_ es que pueden ser [_hashables_](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-hashable), algo que sólo es cierto si todos sus elementos son inmutables. Esto equivale a decir que si dos tuplas valen lo mismo, son la misma tupla, pudiendo usarse en claves de diccionarios o para construir conjuntos (_sets_).

Answer (score -2):

Las tuplas son más eficientes porque tienen menos características que las listas. Por ejemplo, no permiten ser modificadas, y tampoco permiten usar ciertos metodos.